# Function wont repeat

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function passive(){
    $('.div_level_1_active').
      removeClass('div_level_1_active').
      addClass('div_level_1_passive');

    $(this).
      removeClass('div_level_1_passive').
      addClass('div_level_1_active');
  }

  $('.div_level_1_passive').on("click", passive);
});
```

The code above shows a simple button click which will open a box. The error is that once I use this event I cant use it again. I have used functions so that the method can be used more than once but it wont work.

Update from comment:

"I fixed it with this. Thank you for your time I am unless at getting my point across. ":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function passive(thisObject) {
        $('.div_level_1_active').removeClass('div_level_1_active').addClass('div_leve‌​l_1_passive');
        $(thisObject).removeClass('div_level_1_passive').addClass('div_level_1_active');
    }
    function active(thisObject) {
        $(thisObject).removeClass('div_level_1_active').addClass('div_level_1_passive');
    }
    $('.div_level_1_passive').click(function () {
        passive(this);
    });
    $('.div_level_1_active').click(function () {
        active(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: What would happen when you click it again?

Comment: Nothing for example if you had four boxes all named fox and you then selected one box normally the class will change which is does but when I select another box the class is added to that box and removed from the first box but when I return to open the first box the code wont run because I have already selected that div.

Comment: @MattClaff: Your solution does not look correct. The click event handlers will still disconnect when you remove/add the classes so the click will only work once. `Paul Roub`/`BeNdErR`'s solutions should be the correct answer if you require the clicks to keep working more than once.

Answer (score 3):

Your `on()` will only apply to `.div_level_1_passive` elements that existed at the time it was called. You want to handle those that appear later (as in your click handler):

```
$(document).on("click", '.div_level_1_passive', passive);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/kemay

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 function passive(thisObject){
   $('.div_level_1_active').removeClass('div_level_1_active').addClass('div_level_1_passive');
     $(thisObject).removeClass('div_level_1_passive').addClass('div_level_1_active');
 }
 function active(thisObject){
     $(thisObject).removeClass('div_level_1_active').addClass('div_level_1_passive');
 }
 $('.div_level_1_passive').click(function(){
  passive(this);
 });
 $('.div_level_1_active').click(function(){
   active(this);
 });
});

I fixed it with this. Thank you for your time I am unless at getting my point across.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
  $(document).on("click", ".div_level_1_passive", passive);
```

to bind the click event. this will apply to all the elements with the div_level1_passive class, even if added after you bound the click event

Comment: still does the same result. my theory to make this work would be to transfer $(this) to the function so then I can just select that specific div like you would normally do.